# axios Request failed with status code 404 (react,mongodb)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm trying to implement login/register functions using React and MongoDB. I did registration and login and now I want to add to a different schema but I'm facing an error.

Note: http://localhost:3001/register and login paths are both working.

Here is the error message I'm facing when the axios request is made:

> "message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'"

Here are the code snippets I have tried:

file: `model-classes.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ClassesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    classname : String,
})

const ClassesModel = mongoose.model('classes', ClassesSchema);

module.exports = ClassesModel;
```

file: `index.js`

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const FormDataModel = require ('../models/FormData');
const FormData2Model = require ('../models/Classes');


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://amirpellman:*******@cluster.kwcktyi.mongodb.net/');

app.post('/addclass', (req, res)=>{
    // To post / insert data into database

    const {email, password} = req.body;
    FormData2Model.findOne({email: email})
    .then(user => {
        if(user){
            res.json("Already registered")
        }
        else{
            FormData2Model.create(req.body)
            .then(log_reg_form2 => res.json(log_reg_form2))
            .catch(err => res.json(err))
        }
    })
    
})
```

file: `screen-addclass.js`

```js
    const [classname, setClassname] = useState();
   

    const handleSubmit1 = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        axios.post( 'http://localhost:3001/addclass', {classname})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            if(result.data === "Already registered"){
                alert("E-mail already registered! Please Login to proceed.");
            }
            else{
                alert("Registered successfully! Please Login to proceed.")
            }
            
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err),alert("asdas"));
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center vh-100" style= {{backgroundImage : "linear-gradient(#00d5ff,#0095ff,rgba(93,0,255,.555))"}}>
            <div className="bg-white p-3 rounded" style={{width : '40%'}}>
                <h2 className='mb-3 text-primary'>Register</h2>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit1}>
                    <div className="mb-3 text-start">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
                            <strong >Name</strong>
                        </label>
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Enter Name"
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="exampleInputname" 
                            onChange={(event) => setClassname(event.target.value)}
                            required
                        /> 
                    </div>
                  
                   
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </form>

                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Addclass
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be no `email` or `password` in the `req.body`, as the `classname` in the **addclass.js** doesn't contain it.

You need to modify the post request as follows:

```
const handleSubmit1 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const details = { 
       email : classname,
       // you can also include password in the this
    }
    
    axios.post( 'http://localhost:3001/addclass', details)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        if(result.data === "Already registered"){
            alert("E-mail already registered! Please Login to proceed.");
        }
        else{
            alert("Registered successfully! Please Login to proceed.")
        }
        
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err),alert("asdas"));
}
```

Also include error-handling in api-services. Use `try-catch` and check for the log in the **terminal**, that will be useful for debugging.